# German pronunciation dictionary for CMU Sphinx

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am looking for a German pronunciation dictionary in order to use for PocketSphinx / CMU Sphinx.

The dictionary looks like this:

```
BACK    B AE K
CALL    K AO L
NO  N OW
NUMBER  N AH M B ER
ONE W AH N
ONE(2)  HH W AH N
REPLY   R IH P L AY
REPLY(2)    R IY P L AY
SEND    S EH N D
STOP    S T AA P
THREE   TH R IY
TWO T UW
YES Y EH S
```

It is no problem to find these for English, but I can't find them for German. Do you have any idea where to find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those who are looking for one, I found a lexicon at http://www.repository.voxforge1.org/downloads/de/Archive/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried German model with **pocketsphinx**.

Сheck the [official model files storage](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/).

The list I have used:

- **fst** = voxforge-de.fst
- **hmm folder** =  model_parameters/voxforge.cd_cont_6000
- **dictionary** =  cmusphinx-voxforge-de.dic
- **language model** =  **cmusphinx-voxforge-de.lm.gz**

To get hmm path you should unzip: cmusphinx-de-voxforge-5.2.tar.gz

I think that it should be the same for a Sphinx4, so can give a try.

Models (2018-2017)